# Do we know the limit of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(a i k+b)^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I am not sure if the closed- form of this limit is known ($i$ is the imaginary one):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(a i k+b)^2}$$

If it's not, then yay, I found it. But I think it's very unlikely that it's not already known, as with anything else I've found out.

**Edit:**
All right, I just checked the answer with the Polygamma on Mathematica, and it doesn't give it a closed-form, but I do have and am adding it here.

Please don't vandalize the rating of this post otherwise I won't be able to add the details.

> $$\Re\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(aik+b)^2}\right)=-\frac1{2b^2}+\frac1{2(1-e^{-2\pi b/a})^2}\left(\frac{2\pi}a\right)^2e^{-2\pi b/a}$$

**Edit:**
Attending to the request of the mods, I want to clarify that the question is about if a closed-form for the below was already known (see my answer for the real part):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(a i j k+b)^k}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89510/discussion-on-question-by-jr-s-do-we-know-the-limit-of-sum-limits-k1n-f).

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Clarified in an edit. If still not ok, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the formula I found for the general case. If someone knows if this result is already known, please let me know by posting links to papers or pages.

I will claim it as a different proof nonetheless on my arXiv paper, which I will post here when I'm done:

\begin{multline}\nonumber
h(x)=\sum _{k=2}^{\infty}\sum _{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{(a j+b)^k}=-\frac{x^2}{2b(b-x)}+\frac{\pi x}{2a}\csc{\frac{\pi b}{a}}\csc{\frac{\pi (b-x)}{a}}\sin{\frac{\pi x}{a}}\\-\frac{x \pi}{a}\int _0^1\left(\csc{\frac{2 \pi (b-x)}{a}}\sin{\frac{2 \pi (b-x)u}{a}}-\csc{\frac{2
\pi b}{a}}\sin{\frac{2 \pi  b u}{a}}\right)\cot{\pi u}\,du
\end{multline}

**On the limits of a generalized harmonic progression:**

https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06885

Comment: That's very impressive! I was barely able to find the value at k=2.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thank you so much, that's why I'll upload a paper on arXiv.

Comment: @PeterForeman I didn't know this sum converged for $k=1$ also. It seems things work differently with complex numbers.

Comment: In that case the real part is $(\pi b \coth{(\frac{\pi b}{a})} - a)/(2 ab)$. It seems that the imaginary part of this summation is always harder to calculate. Hope you can find the general solution to that as well!

Comment: @PeterForeman I finished the whole thing, I posted an edit to my answer.

Comment: @JR Sousa Your result is very interesting, but I think it is not a good idea to post it as an answer to a question which is much more narrow. Besides, as I asked in another post, is it you who have asked the same question on Quora.com/ with a very valuable  answer there : the connection with a known function : Hurwitz zeta function.

Comment: @JeanMarie It probably was me, as I post on Quora too. However, on Quora we hardly get answers for harder questions. Yes, the Lerch-Hurwitz formula appears on my formula for the harmonic progression, as detailed in that paper.

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree, it's very interesting, and I've checked the results on Mathematica. It yields the limits both for each individual harmonic progression of order k by means of the derivatives at 0 and all of them combined. It only doesn't apply when $2b/a$ and $2(b-x)/a$ are integers, but it seems those cases have a trivial derivation, which I'm trying to write another paper on.

Answer (score 7):

So we have 
$$\frac1{(aik+b)^2}=\frac{1}{b^2-a^2k^2+2abki}$$
$$=\frac{b^2-a^2k^2-2abki}{(b^2-a^2k^2)^2+(2abk)^2}$$
$$=\frac{b^2-a^2k^2-2abki}{b^4-2a^2b^2k^2+a^4k^4+4a^2b^2k^2}$$
$$=\frac{b^2-a^2k^2-2abki}{b^4+2a^2b^2k^2+a^4k^4}$$
$$=\frac{b^2-a^2k^2-2abki}{(b^2+a^2k^2)^2}$$
$$=\frac{b^2-a^2k^2}{(b^2+a^2k^2)^2}-\frac{2abki}{(b^2+a^2k^2)^2}$$
$$\therefore \Re\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(aik+b)^2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b^2-a^2k^2}{(b^2+a^2k^2)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{d}{da}\Bigg(\frac{a}{b^2+a^2k^2}\Bigg)$$
$$=\frac{d}{da}\Bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a}{b^2+a^2k^2}\Bigg)$$
$$=\frac{d}{da}\Bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(b/a)^2+k^2}\Bigg)$$
$$=\frac{d}{da}\Bigg(\frac{1}{a}\frac{\pi (\frac{b}{a})\coth{(\frac{\pi b}{a})} - 1}{2 (\frac{b}{a})^2}\Bigg)$$
$$=\frac{d}{da}\Bigg(\frac{\pi b \coth{(\frac{\pi b}{a})} - a}{2 b^2}\Bigg)$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{2a^2\sinh^2{(\frac{\pi b}{a})}}-\frac{1}{2b^2}$$

Which is the same as your result with some rearrangement.

Comment: @J R Sousa Are you the author of the synchroneous following question https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-closed-form-for-sum_-j-1-infty-frac-1-a-i-j-b-k-for-k-geq-2-Here-i-is-the-imaginary-unit-and-a-b-are-real with an answer that links the issue to **Hurwitz zeta function** ?

Comment: No I am not the author.

Comment: This question wasn't intended for you but for J R Sousa. I should have placed it under his question (or under his answer that he validates : I am surprized that this is possible).

Comment: @JeanMarie I posted the question, but the answer was not me, it was a guy named Senya. I wanted to know if there was an expression for this series.